# Convert matrix of char to column vector of date

Tags: matlab

I have a function that expects dates to be in `column vector` `1x2 of DateTime`. If my data is in this `2x20 of char` like this, [I am using two values to make it simple - the answer should work for any number of dates char-strings-dates]

```
2x20 of char

    20-Sep-2017 15:35:00
    20-Sep-2017 15:40:00
```

**How do I convert to**

```
Columns 1 through 2 of DateTime

    20-Sep-2017 15:35:00  20-Jan-2017 15:40:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t = datetime(datesStrings(1:end,:))
t = t'
```